# Canvas to PDF, HTML, Konva.js

Tags: javascript, html, konva

I am working about draggable objects on Konva stage. I want to the canvas object layer turn to PDF. I use toDataURL. Like this;

```
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height,
    id: 'stage',
});


var grid_layer = new Konva.Layer();
var object_layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(grid_layer);
stage.add(object_layer);

function updateScreen() {
    object_layer.batchDraw()
}
function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function() {
    var dataURL = stage.toDataURL({ pixelRatio: 3 });
    downloadURI(dataURL, 'stage.png');
  },
  false
);
```

Save button work without objects  and save canvas image. But when i run the code with objects on stage, the page reloads and the button doesn't work. doesn't save canvas image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to doing it like shown in the [Konva Wiki](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Canvas_to_PDF.html).

```
// Code form KonvaJS wiki
var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', [stage.width(), stage.height()]);
pdf.setTextColor('#000000');
// first add texts
stage.find('Text').forEach((text) => {
    const size = text.fontSize() / 0.75; // convert pixels to points
    pdf.setFontSize(size);
    pdf.text(text.text(), text.x(), text.y(), {
        baseline: 'top',
        angle: -text.getAbsoluteRotation(),
    });
});

// then put image on top of texts (so texts are not visible)
pdf.addImage(
    stage.toDataURL({ pixelRatio: 2 }),
    0,
    0,
    stage.width(),
    stage.height()
);

pdf.save('canvas.pdf');
```

This should add all text and other objects to a pdf.

Comment: i checkhed this. But it dosent work. The error written on the console is 'Konva error: Unable to get data URL. Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported. For more info read https://konvajs.org/docs/posts/Tainted_Canvas.html.' and
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/konva%20-%20Kopya/index.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.'

Comment: Do you use pictures which are stored local or are they on a server?

Comment: I saved the pictures locally

Comment: Have you tried adding the "img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous'" attribute when adding the images?

Comment: Yes, i tried adding this, the result is negative

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I can conclude that you don't host the images using the server you use for the konva stuff. You can't access the images from your website as they are not from the same origin. This helps secure the files on your computer from the access of websites like yours. So you would have to move the images to the server and access them from there.